# invert the input array

Tags: c++

i have write a little code in c++ that take in input an array and this will be inverted.
the first become last , second become penultimate and so on...
here the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int length=3;

void exch(int arr_exch[]){
int s,e,tmp;
s=0;
e=length-1;
while ((e-s!=1)||(e-s!=0)){
tmp=arr_exch[s];
arr_exch[e]=arr_exch[s];
arr_exch[s]=tmp;
s=s+1;
e=e-1;
}
}

int main()
{
int arr[length],counter;

  cout << "enter "<< length <<" integers:\n";
  for (counter=0; counter<length; counter++){
  cin >> arr[counter];
  }
  exch (arr[]);   **<--- here the error "expected primary expression before ']' token.**
  for (counter=0; counter<length; counter++){
  cout << arr[counter]<<"\t";
  }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is - for now - segmentation fault and "expected primary expression before ']' token. i don t know how to correct it. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you manage to get a segmentation fault (which is a **runtime**) error, if your code doesn't even compile? Why aren't you using whitespace and indentation for formatting your code? Why aren't you using a debugger?

Comment: Be an angel and format your code correctly. It would be much easier to read if you do that.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Perhaps the compiler performed a segmentation fault while attempting to compile this code (I'm pretty sure I would).

Comment: @barakmanos haha, fair enough :D

Comment: @alf - well, it could be the real code. problem is people tend to compile, then run whatever a.out is left lying around  :-(

Comment: @VishalGupta How can a java question be a dupe for c++ (when it's about concrete code explicitly)?

Comment: I removed my comment. We can refer logic from that java question.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit puzzle to me your code is not even compiling and you got segmentation fault. How come?

Anyway change this

```
exch (arr[]);
```

to

```
exch (arr);
```

You generally get segmentation fault while accessing invalid memory OR memory you are not allowed to access and this can only happen when you execute your code that means after successfully compiling your code.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your question is that you want to reverse an array.

In the while loop within your code, you are trying to access the arr_exch array with index -1 which is causing the segmentation fault error.

You can try the below code which is working fine.

```
#include <iostream>

const int length = 3;
// exch1() is another way for reversing a array.
void exch1(int arr_exch[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++) {
        int temp = arr_exch[i];

        arr_exch[i] = arr_exch[length - i - 1];
        arr_exch[length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
void exch(int arr_exch[]){
    int tmp = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int e = length - 1;

    while (e > s){  
        tmp = arr_exch[s];
        arr_exch[s] = arr_exch[e];
        arr_exch[e] = tmp;
        s = s + 1;
        e = e - 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[length];

    std::cout << "enter "<< length <<" integers:\n";
    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
        std::cin >> arr[counter];
    }
    exch(arr);   //**<--- here the error "expected primary expression before ']' token.**
    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
        std::cout << arr[counter] << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```